# ruby: copy directories recursively with link dereferencing

Tags: ruby

It's very strange, I cannot find any **standard** way with Ruby to copy a directory recursively while dereferencing symbolic links. The best I could find is `FindUtils.cp_r` but it only supports dereferencing the root src directory.

`copy_entry` is the same although documentation falsely shows that it has an option `dereference`. In source it is `dereference_root` and it does only that.

Also I can't find a **standard** way to recurse into directories. If nothing good exists, I can write something myself but wanted something simple and tested to be portable across Windows and Unix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my implementation of `find -follow` in ruby:

https://gist.github.com/akostadinov/05c2a976dc16ffee9cac

I could have isolated it into a class or monkey patch Find but I decided to do it as a self-contained method. There might be room for improvement <del>because it doesn't work with jruby. If anybody has an idea, it will be welcome</del>.

Update: found out why not working with jruby - https://github.com/jruby/jruby/issues/1895
<del>I'll try to workaround.</del> I implemented a workaround.

Update 2: now `cp_r_dereference` method ready - https://gist.github.com/akostadinov/fc688feba7669a4eb784

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to recurse into directories is to use the [Find](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/find/rdoc/index.html) class but I think you're going to have to write something. The built-in [FileUtils](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/index.html) methods are building blocks for normal operations but your need is not normal.

I'd recommend looking at the [Pathname](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/index.html) class which comes with Ruby. It makes it easy to walk directories using [`find`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-find), look at the type of the file and dereference it if necessary. In particular [`symlink?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-symlink-3F) will tell you if a file is a soft-link and [`realpath`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-realpath) will resolve the link and return the path to the real file.

For instance I have a soft-link in my home directory from `.vim` to `vim`:

```
vim = Pathname.new ENV['HOME'] + '/.vim'
=> #<Pathname:/Users/ttm/.vim>
vim.realpath
=> #<Pathname:/Users/ttm/vim>
```

Pathname is quite powerful, and I found it very nice when having to do some major directory traversals and working with soft-links. The docs say:

> The goal of this class is to manipulate file path information in a neater way than standard Ruby provides. [...]
>
> All functionality from File, FileTest, and some from Dir and FileUtils is included, in an unsurprising way. It is essentially a facade for all of these, and more.

If you use `find`, you'll probably want to implement the `prune` method which is used to skip entries you don't want to recurse into. I couldn't find it in Pathname when I was writing code so I added it using something like:

```
class Pathname
  def prune
    Find.prune
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. btw this usage is IMO normal. Maybe not in windows wrold but on unix it is pretty normal to copy with dereferencing links.

Comment: I can recurse into dir and use the standard FileUtils.cp with dereference option to copy individual files. Thanks.

Comment: wrt the prune method, I guess one can simply use the `Find.prune` directly. I really don't like monkey patching as it adds too much complexity when debugging. Thanks for answer. I've implemented something based on these classes.